# How to decide whether a multivariable polynomial lies in an ideal before doing division

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> How to decide whether multivariable polynomial $f$ lies in ideal $I = \langle f_1, f_2 \rangle$ before doing division to find  $a_1, a_2 \in k[X,Y]$?

I've solved an exercise stated like this:

Decide whether $f = X^2+X^4+X^2Y + X^3Y-Y^2+XY^2$ lies in $I = \langle X^2+Y, X+Y \rangle$. If so compute $a_1, a_2 \in k[X,Y]$ such that $f = a_1(X^2+Y)+a_2(X+Y)$.

Trying different ways of dividing by $(X^2+Y, X+Y)$ I finally got an answer, namely $a_1 = 0, a_2 = XY-Y+X^3+X$. Thus I could conclude that $f$ lies in $I$ and write $f$ as a product of the polynomials in $I$.

However how can I decide from the beginning if $f\in I$ without doing division ? Since I should decide whether $f$ lies in $I$ before computing $a_1,a_2$ it really sounds like there should be some method of checking whether there exists some way as writing $f$ as $a_1f_1 + a_2f_2$ before trying division ? If $f \notin I$ there dont exists $a_1,a_2$, and this would be nice to know. Could someone tell me how ?

Comment: There isn't a way in general probably unless it's some algorithm more complicated than division, in that case useless here.